# Reducing duplicate JOIN clauses produced by SQLAlchemy

Tags: join, sqlalchemy

I'm currently having trouble finding a way to reduce superfluous `JOIN` clauses produced by SQLAlchemy eager loading. I am currently querying `TableA`, which eagerly loads `TableB`, and `TableB` eagerly loads `TableC`.

My queries also invole *explicit* joins to both `TableB` and `TableC` in order to filter on columns of those tables. However, it produces verbose SQL such as the following:

```
  SELECT * FROM TableA 
           JOIN TableB             ON TableA.fk == TableB.id
           JOIN TableC             ON TableB.fk == TableC.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS TableB_1 ON TableA.fk == TableB.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC AS TableC_1 ON TableB.fk == TableC.id
```

I'm currently using `lazy='joined'` on the backreferences to eagerly load `TableB` and `TableC` from `TableA` queries. Loading this data with a subquery creates an N+1 select issue (so switching from eager to lazy loading is not an option).

I've tried also adding `innerjoin=True` to the backreference, which replaced the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` clauses with inner joins (just `JOIN` in the output). I was hoping that SQLAlchemy would merge identical join clauses, but it doesn't seem to.

Is there a way to specify either on the query or on the relationship that identical join clauses should not be duplicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show us the code? It is not clear what exactly are you doing.

To eagerly populate relationship collections from explicit joins you should use `contains_eager` option instead of `joinedload`. I.e.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import contains_eager, joinedload

session.query(ModelA).join(ModelB).options(contains_eager(ModelA.bs_list)).all()
```

as opposed to

```
session.query(ModelA).join(ModelB).options(joinedload(ModelA.bs_list)).all()
```

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked the `contains_eager` section in the relationship documentation. That was exactly what I was looking for.